# Why is being explicit in C++ required?

Tags: c++

In C++, you have to be explicit about many things, like using delete.  This gives the programmer more options, but, it doesn't always make sense to me.  For example: initializing an array of characters in the constructor.  Why aren't simple tasks like these can be handled easier than this way:

```
class x{
enum {Lim =20};
char a[Lim];

x(const char* s){
strncpy(a, s, Lim - 1);
a[Lim - 1] = '\0';
}
}
```

In, C#, all you have to do is:

```
class loai { 
public char[] a;
public loai(char[] a) {
    this.a = a;
}
}
```

P.S: Sorry for yesterday. I was tired and couldn't express my ideas well. Thanks

Comment: @Loai Najati: I would suggest putting a ? at the end of your question, so it is more obvious that it is a question.

Comment: If you have a specific question, feel free to ask, but we're not going to guess what grudges you have against the language.

Comment: Well, you didn't give me enough time to fix that and guess what? my native language isn't English. So, it's not that easy to express my ideas in it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: C++ has the ability to function as *low level* language. That means not paying for anything you don't use, and having to be very explicit about what you want. It also has the ability to function as a reasonably high level language.  That flexibility comes at a cost, and sometimes you need to bring in some extra libraries.

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by initializing an array of characters. It's quite possible to define a placeholder for a certain number of characters (e.g., a buffer) but not actually wanting to pay the price of putting values in there during construction just to have them erased. If you want to put something there, you can just use the assignment style of defining it (e.g., char x[]="BlaBlaBla").

Comment: @Loai: That's okay, take your time. Write up a list of tiny questions you have and put them in your question, I'm sure we'll reopen it and answer them. But as it stands, there are *so* many tiny things in the language we can't possibly try to pick out the questions you want to know.

Comment: I'm with Neil on the tags, BTW. *Don't* stick a close reason in the tags: they don't belong there. If you don't have the power to vote to close, you can write a comment.

Comment: @Loai: Reword your question. Give code examples of what you're talking about. Be more specific. No one is going to try to guess what you could possibly be talking about.

Answer (score 5):

You can initialize an array of characters....

```
char a[] = "hello";
```

Comment: Because that's not what I was talking about.

Comment: Well you specifically asked why it was not possible to initialize an array of characters.... Seems to me like that is exactly what you asked.  I do understand though that you were looking for a more generalized answer, but I think there are only specific answers to your specific questions (Whatever they may be).

Comment: The question wasn't clear, but I interpreted it as a character array non-static data member, for which this answer wouldn't apply.

Comment: @Roger Pate: `a` is not a pointer to a static memory block, it is an array on the stack and it is initialized; therefore, yes this answer does apply.

Comment: Brian: `struct A { char a[20]; };`, A::a is a non-static data member.  Your answer doesn't apply to this case.  The question wasn't clear.

Comment: @Roger Pate: Ya he could have meant that too.

Answer (score 2):

By and large, **you *can* make simple tasks less tedious**.  For example, use smart pointers such as auto_ptr, boost::shared_ptr, or scoped_ptr and you won't have to call delete yourself.  Use functions such as std::fill, specify the initializer for arrays, or use a different type (caveats and examples below, and more functionality available in C++0x).

```
struct A {
  char s[20];
  A() : s() { assert(s[0] == '\0'); /*always true*/ }
  // you can only use the "default ctor", in this case char(), which is equal
  // to '\0'
};
// of course, if the item type of the array has a non-trivial ctor, it will
// always be called for each item even if you leave the array member out of
// the ctor init list
```

```
struct B {
  char s[20];
  B() { std::fill(s, s + boost::size(s), 'a'); s[boost::size(s)-1] = '\0'; }
  // and if this is common, write your own function
  // even make it a private static function if it's only used within this class
  // (e.g. each ctor calls it, or several methods do)
private:
  template <int N>
  static void fill_null_term(char (&a)[N], char value) {
    // fill and null terminate
    fill(a, a + N - 1, value);
    a[N-1] = '\0';
  }
  // notice two things:
  // 1) certainly possible to pull this out of the class as required
  // 2) don't hardcode constants, use the type system to your advantage
  //    (passing the array length) when possible
};
```

```
struct C {
  std::string s;
  C() : s(19, 'a') {}
  // mentioned last, but this would really be the first solution you use;
  // refactoring to something else, such as A and B, as requirements change
  // or are more clearly defined
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged your question as C++, consider following:

```
class x
{
public:
    explicit x(const std::string &str)
        : str_(str)
    {}

    explicit x(const char *str)
        : str_(str ? str : "")
    {}

    ~x() {}

private:
    std::string str_;
};
```

Don't see how C++ would make me be too explicit in any way. Yes, `std::string` is not exactly an array of characters, but, ask yourself, do you *really* need it? I wouldn't expect `std::string` to perform considerably worse than a char array in probably 99% of possible use cases. So, don't make your life complicated, use the good things that C++ provides you, not the things left for C compatibility, unless you absolutely need to and know what you're doing.

**EDIT:** Ah, I see, the `explicit` keyword adds "explicitness" to C++ :) Keep forgetting it on a first round of typing.

Comment: Actually, I would expect `std::string` to perform better than a char array in most cases, as `std::string`s know their own length, and so their length doesn't need to be recalculated all the time. (Of course, `char[]` can be supplied with a length as well, but this is tedious and often not done.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler C++ version, which looks almost exactly like your C# sample:

```
class loai { 
public:
  std::vector<char> a;
  loai(const std::vector<char>& a) : a(a) {}
};
```

Of course you can make everything awfully complicated by using the wrong datatypes, regardless of language. In C++, plain arrays are very simple types, and so in many cases, something like `std::vector` is more convenient to use.